# Showing a set is closed with sequences

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$G \subset R^n$

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in N}$ a convergent sequence in $G$,  ($x_k \in G$ for every $k$). $lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = a$ lays in $G$. Show that G is a closed set.

Help please, I have already proved the other implication!

Answer (score 1):

$G$ may be not closed.

> For example, the subspace $[0, \omega_1) \subseteq [0, \omega_1]$ with order topology.

If $G$ is first countable, then the claim is true.

> **PROOF:** For any $x \in \overline{G}$, as $G$ is first countable, then there exists a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ such that converges $x$. Then $x \in G$ by the condition. Therefore $\overline{G} \subseteq G$, and hence $\overline{G}=G$.

Comment: Well personally I guess it will be in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ;)

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is OK, as it is always metrizable and hence first countable.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in a normed space then your result is true:

Let $g\in adh(G)$ then 
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*\quad B(g,\frac{1}{n})\cap G\neq\emptyset$$
Let $x_n\in B(g,\frac{1}{n})\cap G$ then we construct a sequence convergent to $g$ so $g\in G$ hence $adh(G)\subset G$ and then $G$ is closed.

Comment: A normeed space is first countable. Your result is my result in special case.